# PHP create filename in hebrew

Tags: javascript, php, html, server, filesystems

I'm trying to create a new filename in hebrew but its displaying in special characters like `"×©×©_×©×©_×©×©.php"`

PHP:

```
$page  = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['page']));

$fh = fopen('../Pages/'.$page.".php", 'w') or die("Can't create file"); 
fclose($fh);
```

Thanks.

Comment: 'htmlspecialchars' can not be used in filenames. Also, one should never want to create files with hebrew characters. Why are you trying to? Is there a specific reason?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `hebrev()`?

```
$page  = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['page']));
```

instead try this

```
$page = hebrev($_POST['page']);
```

this might work.